# Demand forecasting

Tags: forecasting

I am forecasting number of phone calls (y) i ll be getting based on the products sold(x) and I am doing the following:
(forecasted y) = (y/x averaged for past three weeks) * (forecasted x). 
1. Please let me know if this is apt to do there is any other method I can try.
2. Also how should I calculate the percentage change in y based on the percentage change in x

I feel this method is flawed because forecasted y are already forecasted using x historical and then by multiplying  by forecasted x am I increasing the impact of x on y

Thank you so much everyone!

Comment: Where does that formula come from?

Comment: Historically it is assumed that there is a linear dependence of y on x. It is more like (Forecasted y = (historical y/historical x) * (forecasted x)

Comment: But are you just assuming this is true, or do you have some data to back it up - your formula? My question is, why are you fixing your formula to be such? Why not use a model to determine this?

Comment: Historically this formula worked well. However, now I am seeing a huge MAPE in the forecasted numbers. I also tried y as a rate of time using simple moving averages and ARIMA in R, the results were okay but I want to utilize the x dependent variable. What will be a starting point to redo this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not let ARIMA decide the model? You can include exogenous variables in ARIMAX, so that is not an issue.

Comment: Will I be able to add the following variables in that case: • Holidays/Peaks 
• Products sold
• Product delivery method
• Calls/ products sold and accuracy of delivery of product

Comment: Yes, any continuous or discrete variable will do.

Comment: Thanks! the info you provided was very helpful..i ll work on it and will ask more questions :)